# How to counter Riki ?

Tags: dota

I am wondering how is it possible to counter Rikimaru?

SCENARIO:
Farming solo on the upper lane. Gem on me. Get blinked/smoked/purged. I'm dead. For the sake of the argument he has butter/bahser also.

What is there to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Scenario**:

Say you have bkb. He can't purge but let's say he went for skady not diffusal. You are dead.

Say you have hex. He has bkb. You are dead.

Say you have eul. You stand in the air for a good amount of time. Smoke is almost out. He gets in fog trees as you are in air. He blinks/smoke,your eul is on cd(smoke has less cd). You are  dead.

Say you have forceStaff/ghost scepter. You actually can get out of smoke. Now we are talking. There is an ok amount of heroes that can **wipe riki out of smoke**, although I can't think of a ranged carry which could(sylla ranged and troll ranged would fail also).

**DoomBringer aka Lucy** - doom him. He can't backstab,bash,blink. He is fresh meat.(yeah farmed **Pudge** can wipe him too)

**Syllabear** Cuirass,double bash,engtangle. 'Nough said.

**Void** Ulti. 'Nough said

**Alchemist** @lvl 16 with ulti and good build just omg.

**Slardar** -armor,Bash,Bash,Bash,Stun,Bash,Bash,Bash. Yeah, you are dead.

**Puck** - now this hero is just imba at evoiding/escaping. If he is really really good you are dead. Slow(ish) damage dealing but silence/Orb+phase shift/dagger/eul/hex/forceStaff and it's just crazy.

Well, here the list might go on. I could add some more heroes in here. Even so,I think the main thing you gotta think about is getting out of the smoke. Then, you have a good range of possibilities.

Also, if you have a carry hero, go for MKB for **truestrike** and then if you are feeling confident go for the kill in the smoke as you have no miss chance, but still you can't use your skills. Even so, this is doable.

Comment: Scenario: you are on your lane farming, riki comes and jumps. 2-3 allies come and help you to kill riki. case closed. this game is a 5v5, not a 1v1. dont run alone, get alot of disable and wards and you should be fine

Comment: Nice thinking. 3 allies come to help you kill riki which means you have 2 lanes defended by 1 hero against 4 enemy heroes. Good thinking :)

Comment: its just common sense to guard your own carry and try to gank their carry (riki). therefore playing a semitrilane (2 on lane, 1 woods) is nothing extraordinary. just saying that a 1v1 in late is pretty uncommon or as stated above "dont run alone". your answer is still right.

Comment: Well you are right, but as the scenario was "top lane farming alone", I answered the question having this in mind. Probably I would have answered totaly different if the scenario was different.

Comment: He was asking a specific question: ofc the best thing to do is to sentry ward the lane where riki tends to be to prevent him farming and harass him, but this is not what OP asked.